# StateFlow triggers multiple times when used to navigate to other Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, kotlin-stateflow

I have been using StateFlow + sealed interfaces to represent the various UI states in my Android app. In my ViewModel I have a sealed interface `UiState` that does this, and the various states are exposed as a `StateFlow`:

```kotlin
sealed interface UiState {
    class LocationFound(val location: CurrentLocation) : UiState
    object Loading : UiState
    // ...
    class Error(val message: String?) : UiState
}


@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getLocationUseCase: GetLocationUseCase): ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState

// ...
}
```

Then in a Composable, I observe the events in this manner:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel,
    onLocationFound: (CurrentLocation) -> Unit,
    onSnackbarButtonClick: () -> Unit
) {

// ...
    LaunchedEffect(true) { viewModel.getLocation() }
    when (val state = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value) {
        is UiState.LocationFound -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "MyScreen: LocationFound")
            onLocationFound.invoke(state.location)
        }
        UiState.Loading -> LoadingScreen
        // ...
    }

}
```

In my MainActivity.kt, when `onLocationFound` callback is invoked, I am supposed to navigate to another destination (`Screen2`) in the `NavGraph`:

```kotlin
enum class Screens {
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
   // ...
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            MyTheme {
                MyNavHost(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyNavHost(navController: NavHostController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.Home.name) {
        composable(Screens.Screen1.name) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>()
            MyScreen(viewModel = viewModel, onLocationFound = {
                navController.navigate(
                    "${Screens.Screen2.name}/${it.locationName}/${it.latitude}/${it.longitude}"
                )
            }, onSnackbarButtonClick = { // ... }
            )
        }
        // ....
        composable("${Screens.Screen2.name}/{location}/{latitude}/{longitude}", arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("location") { type = NavType.StringType },
            navArgument("latitude") { type = NavType.StringType },
            navArgument("longitude") { type = NavType.StringType }
        )) {
            // ... 
        }
    }
}
```

But what happens is that the `onLocationFound` callback seems to be hit multiple times as I can see the logging that I've placed show up multiple times in Logcat, thus I navigate to the same location multiple times resulting in an annoying flickering screen. I checked that in  `MyViewmodel`, I am definitely not setting `_uiState.value = LocationFound` multiple times. Curiously enough, when I wrap the invocation of the callback with `LaunchedEffect(true)`, `LocationFound` gets called only two times, which is still weird but at least there's no flicker.

But still, `LocationFound` should only get called once. I have a feeling that recomposition or some caveat with Compose navigation is in play here but I've researched and can't find the right terminology to look for.

Comment: I do not have time to look at your code, but I think you should study this in order to understand better what is going on: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events